# Automatic validation of form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

So I'm learning ASP.Net MVC5 by following the tutorials on the [Pro ASP.Net MVC 5 book from Apress](http://www.apress.com/9781430265290).

The thing is that on chapter 11 he mentions how to validate a form on the client side by adding the following scripts to the view that needs validation (and to the project using Nuget):

```
<script src="∼/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"/>
<script src="∼/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"/>
<script src="∼/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"/>
```

After doing so, and with the model attribute's set, I find that not all of the properties are validated when the input field loses the focus, even though the HTML is correctly (from my understanding) on all of them.

So what I have is, for the model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a product name")]
public string Name { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a product description")]
public string Description { get; set; }
```

The scripts have been added to a Layout file following the book's instructions and the HTML generated is as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input name="Name" class="form-control input-validation-error" id="Name" type="text" 
         value="Kayak" data-val-required="Please enter a product name" data-val="true">
  <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Name">
    <span for="Name" generated="true">Please enter a product name</span>
  </span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Description</label>
  <textarea name="Description" class="form-control" id="Description" rows="5" cols="20" 
           data-val-required="Please enter a product description" data-val="true"></textarea>
  <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true"
        data-valmsg-for="Description"></span>
 </div>
```

So according to the book, both fields should be showing the error when the control loses the focus, but right now only the "Name" one is doing it (you can see that in the picture, 2 out of 4 fields are validated, same situation on the other two as described above):

[image]

So the question is, what am I missing here?

**Update**
Just in case it may be useful, on the browser console I get this warning at the time of loading the page:

> HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the
>   requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier). (XHR): GET -
>   http://localhost:61338/Content/bootstrap-theme.css

I'm using Microsoft Edge to execute the site.

**Update 2**
I updated to use the `jquery-1.10.2.js` version. Same results.

Comment: Something looks wrong with the html you have shown - your `Name` textbox has `value="Kayak"` which means its valid, yet its displaying a validation error. Are you actually changing the text in the `textarea` and then deleting it? (client side validation is lazy, meaning it is not triggered until you change the value - just tabbing through a control will not trigger validation)

Comment: @StephenMuecke What I did is open the form to edit the entity, focus on the control, delete the value (backspace) and tabbed away. If instead I go to the create new entry (which passes a new instance of the model object with all properties empty), no validation is shown. Even when tabbing through the fields.

Comment: That's by design (so you don't get annoying error messages just tabbing through the form to get to where you want to edit. If you tab into the `textarea`, enter some text, tab out, then tab back in and delete the text, you will see the error (once the value has been initially changed, validation is called on `keyup()` rather than `.blur()`). And when you submit, all controls in the form will be validated

Comment: @StephenMuecke Nothing happens if I do that. Meaning: Add object, put info on all the fields. Focus the first one, remove all info, tab, repeat. No validation error is shown here, unless I click on the add button (in which case, all validation is done server side).

Comment: I cannot duplicate the behavior your describing. Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KaZX1g) - set the focus to the textbox and enter some text and tab out, then tab back in and delete it (an error will be shown). Then tab into the textarea, add some text and tab out, then tab back in and delete it (and error will also be shown). If you then enter text in either, the error will be removed as soon as the first character is typed

Comment: @StephenMuecke I see the correct behaviour in your fiddle but only on the Description field. The Name field never shows the validation. I tried my website AND your fiddle on Chrome and Firefox and while the fiddle works the same in all three, my site in firefox validates the description but not the name, and in chrome it just doesnt validate anything. Im starting to think the problem comes from the browsers... Could it be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122093/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-nahuel-ianni).